# What is the circuit symbol for a triple gang potentiometer?

Tags: circuit-design, potentiometer, symbol, circuits, drawing

What is the circuit symbol for a triple gang potentiometer?

I've found one possibility for dual gang potentiometers:

[image: dual-gang pot and symbol]
<sub>(Image source: [Components101 - Different Types Of Potentiometers And How To Use Them In Your Designs](https://components101.com/articles/different-types-of-potentiometers-and-how-to-use-them))</sub>

But this symbol can't be extended to 3 or more gangs because wipers are depicted as being on both sides of the resistive element in the drawing.

What is the circuit symbol for a triple (or multi) gang potentiometer?

Comment: maybe a dashed line... something along this example ... https://instrumentationtools.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Gang-Switch-Principle.png

Comment: I would worry less about the symbol and make it something easily understood and unmistakable for oddball parts.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Usually there is some kind of line or dotted line between pots to indicate the mechanical linkage, the symbol below could be extended to three or more pots. Another thing would be to put a note on the page indicating that the pots are linked

[image]
Source:
https://pe2bz.philpem.me.uk/Misc/-%20Audio/-%20Amp/-%20AudioAmpDesignInfo%20$$$/-%20AudioAmpBasics-001/B-003-Potentiometers/pots.htm

Comment: This also goes for anything else where multiple electromechanical devices are mechanically linked, so you may see the same dotted line notation for things like switches and circuit breakers.

Comment: @Hearth Thanks for your comment.  I thought that was the case, but I wasn't sure.  Good to learn from a real EE.

Answer (score 15):

I would use multiple single pot symbols and give them the same reference designator with an A, B, C,... suffix, as done for multi-part ICs.  eg: R5A, R5B, R5C ...

If the schematic layout permitted, I might also show dashed lines between the wipers.